# Destiny the taken king issues

Tags: destiny

I already have the Taken King. What will happen if I install the Legendary Edition? Will it delete my save file?

Comment: Correct me if i am wrong, From the links marked as duplicate (above) in the answers, I dont think it will delete your save file.

Answer (score 1):

I shouldn’t think so. Bungie saves your characters in their servers and ties them to your account. Your characters and their progressions should be safe.